# PHP Multidimensional Array into mySQL DB

Tags: php, mysql, serialization, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to grab data from an XLS file and dump it into an mySQL DB.

I located a php file that will take the contents of the XLS and display them - as tabular data - on a web page.  I have attempted to modify this code to insert my data into a DB.

Here is the function that does the work - and that I have been attempting to modify:

```
function dumpSQL($row_numbers=false,$col_letters=false,$sheet=0) {
        $xlsData = '';
        for($row=1;$row<=$this->rowcount($sheet);$row++) {
            $rowheight = $this->rowheight($row,$sheet);
            for($col=1;$col<=$this->colcount($sheet);$col++) {
                if(!$this->sheets[$sheet]['cellsInfo'][$row][$col]['dontprint']) {
                    // cell value
                    //$val = $this->val($row,$col,$sheet);
                    $xlsData[$row][$col] = $this->val($row,$col,$sheet);
                }
            }
        }
        // Make a MySQL Connection
        mysql_connect("*******", "******", "*******") or die(mysql_error());
        mysql_select_db("***********") or die(mysql_error());
        $sql = "INSERT INTO BEER_LOCATIONS (LOCATION_NAME, LOCATION_STREET, LOCATION_CITY, LOCATION_STATE, LOCATION_ZIPCODE, LOCATION_PHONE, BEER_STYLE ) VALUES ($xlsData)";
        $result = mysql_query("
            $sql
        ") or die(mysql_error());
}
```

I get the following error when I run this code:
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax

I have also tried to remove the portion where it obtains the multidimensional array and just build a static version:

```
$xlsData[0][0] = "Hello World";
$xlsData[0][1] = "38380 - Thirteen Coins-Boren";
$xlsData[0][2] = "125 Boren Ave N";
$xlsData[0][3] = "Seattle";
$xlsData[0][4] = "WA";
$xlsData[0][5] = "98109";
$xlsData[0][6] = "2066822513";
$xlsData[0][7] = "34740 - Georgetown Keg - 1/2 Manny Pale";
$xlsData[1][0] = "Hello World";
$xlsData[1][1] = "38380 - Thirteen Coins-Boren";
$xlsData[1][2] = "125 Boren Ave N";
$xlsData[1][3] = "Seattle";
$xlsData[1][4] = "WA";
$xlsData[1][5] = "98109";
$xlsData[1][6] = "2066822513";
$xlsData[1][7] = "34740 - Georgetown Keg - 1/2 Manny Pale";
$xlsData[2][0] = "Hello World";
$xlsData[2][1] = "38380 - Thirteen Coins-Boren";
$xlsData[2][2] = "125 Boren Ave N";
$xlsData[2][3] = "Seattle";
$xlsData[2][4] = "WA";
$xlsData[2][5] = "98109";
$xlsData[2][6] = "2066822513";
$xlsData[2][7] = "WA";
$xlsData[3][0] = "Hello World";
$xlsData[3][1] = "86036 - Aafes Ft Lewis Class Vi";
$xlsData[3][2] = "Bldg 2202";
$xlsData[3][3] = "Fort Lewis";
$xlsData[3][4] = "WA";
$xlsData[3][5] = "98433";
$xlsData[3][6] = "2539644128";
$xlsData[3][7] = "42624 - Georgetown Keg - 1/4 Manny Pale";
```

I end up with the same error.

I attempted to serialize my data prior to inserting it into my DB:

```
$xlsData = serialize($xlsData);
```

Thanks for any help.

I'm having trouble implementing the mysql_real_escape_string().  It seems like it needs to wrap around the implode(), but I get an error when I try that.

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO BEER_LOCATIONS (LOCATION_NAME, LOCATION_STREET, LOCATION_CITY, LOCATION_STATE, LOCATION_ZIPCODE, LOCATION_PHONE, BEER_STYLE ) VALUES ('" . mysql_real_escape_string(implode("', '", $row)) . "')";
```

I get this error when I try that:
Column count doesn't match value count at row 1

Thanks again.

Comment: This isn't actually serialization you're trying to do. Serialization is when you convert an object/array/etc. to a string so you can store it without losing the structure. When you store an array of values in a database, you're really just adapting them to fit into the database structure.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up regarding serialization.  I removed that code.

Comment: Did you see if my answer works for you yet? :)

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing this:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO BEER_LOCATIONS (LOCATION_NAME, LOCATION_STREET, LOCATION_CITY, LOCATION_STATE, LOCATION_ZIPCODE, LOCATION_PHONE, BEER_STYLE ) VALUES ($xlsData)";
$result = mysql_query("
    $sql
") or die(mysql_error());
```

with this:

```
foreach($xlsData as $row) {
    $sql = "INSERT INTO BEER_LOCATIONS (LOCATION_NAME, LOCATION_STREET, LOCATION_CITY, LOCATION_STATE, LOCATION_ZIPCODE, LOCATION_PHONE, BEER_STYLE ) VALUES ('" . implode("', '", $row) . "')";
    $result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
}
```

You have to insert each row one at a time, so that's what the foreach loop accomplishes. Also, you can't just put the array itself for the values. The `implode()` function turns the array of column values into a string.

**EDIT:** Also, you should probably change `$xlsData = '';` near the beginning of the function to `$xlsData = array();` I'm not actually sure if the way you had it is a problem, but since $xlsData is supposed to be an array, it's better to set it to an empty array than an empty string.

Comment: Also, if there are any commas in your data, it'll break the SQL query. It doesn't look like there are any in the data you provided, so I don't want to give an overcomplicated answer, but you'd actually want to use [mysql_real_escape_string()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) to escape any characters that would be a problem.

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer from another helpful person.  Thanks to everyone who helped me :)

```
implode("', '", array_map('mysql_real_escape_string', $row))
```